# How do I find the 'namespace keyword' of an included file?

Tags: c++, namespaces, include

I'm a novice C++ programmer.
How can I find out the namespace (is this the right word in this context?) for an include like *'iomanip'* or any other?
When using *'std::cout'*, I don't know why it's *'std'* and not something else.

I hope my question is clear and worth asking.

PS: My first post here :)

Comment: The standard library is inside the namespace std, so that would be pretty easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you know that `cout` existed in the first place?

Because you've read the friendly manual, the language standard, a good book, or an online reference. The same applies to everything: Your documentation or reference will *tell* you the namespace in which you find your types.

Generally, everything that's part of the C++ standard library is in the `std` namespace, but some things may well be in a namespace nested within. Notable examples of nested namespaces are `std::placeholders` and `std::chrono`. But you *will* be told the correct namespaces if you read a good reference.

Thanks to @Potatoswatter: Other constructions that use the same scope resolution syntax are static constants of classes. For example, the class `std::ios_base` contains a static member type `seekdir` with static constant values `beg`, `cur` and `end`; those can be accessed via `std::ios_base::beg` etc. Or, since the type `std::ios` inherits from `ios_base`, via `std::ios::beg` etc.

In many ways, a class with only static members is just a glorified namespace, and in the early days of C++ people often used nested classes to "simulate" nested namespaces, which weren't available at the time. The scope resolution syntax is the same.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the manual head line. When they write '*setw*' its '*std::setw*', '*ios_base::precision*' is '*std::ios_base::precision*' ...

Comment: @Pot: Thanks, fixed! Also note that "wide" doesn't have anything to do with "Unicode". It's encoding-agnostic and means "big enough for your platform".

Comment: True, but I plan to avoid anything wide that is not Unicode ;v) . Also, in your fix, `ios_base` is also a class. There are no nested namespaces in `iostream`. `std::relops` and `std::placeholders` are the only ones I've ever used. There's also `std::this_thread` and probably one for regexes… brave new world…

Comment: @Pot: Oh, right, the `ios` stuff is all static constants in the `ios` class. I'll make a note of that. Sorry for that and thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

It's `std` because `cout` etc. are in the standard library, and the entire standard library lives inside the `std` namespace.

Other libraries will probably have their own namespace (e.g. Boost is inside the `boost` namespace).  But you'd have to consult the relevant documentation to find out the details!

Comment: Thanks for your response too :)

Answer (score 2):

To access the functions declared in iostream library we use a namespace which is nothing but a collection of identifiers (variable names & some other type of names) that belong to a group or family..

Now `std` is a namespace and all identifiers in c++ standard library belong to it.
There are 2 ways to refer to a specific identifier that belongs to a namespace:

1. use the using statement at the begining of the program
2. prefix the identifier with the name of namespace followed by 2 colons e.g. `std::cout<<"hello";`